# python cherrypy: how to start long background (stoppable) task

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing, cherrypy

I've built a restful service in python using [cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org), which is multi-thread by default. Thus two different http sessions don't block each other.

For a given endpoint of my API i need a way to start a long (non blocking) background task which i can stop at any time. Actually i am using a new thread to run the task which allows the user to send other requests to the server without wait for the long task to complete. Unfortunately i need also a way to stop the background task at any time, and it seems i can't stop the new thread from the main thread (am i correct?).

```
@cp.expose
@cp.tools.json_in()    
@cp.tools.json_out()
class LongTaskEndpoint(object):

def GET(self):
    thread = Thread(target=longRunningTask, args=())
    thread.start()
    return {"message" : "Long task started"}
```

I've tried [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) Process instead of thread, but this seems to block the main thread (client can't get any response from the server until the background task is completed):

```
@cp.expose
@cp.tools.json_in()    
@cp.tools.json_out()
class LongTaskEndpoint(object):

def GET(self):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=longRunningTask, args=())
    process.start()
    return {"message" : "Long task started"}
```

How can i start a long background task which does not block the main thread (for each http session) and which the server can stop at any moment?

Comment: You should be using some external task queues like RQ or Celery. I think I saw some usable examples of them at SO under the `cherrypy` tag.

Comment: Thank you i ll check it out!